# How to interrupt a call to .read() method on a JeroMQ socket?

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

In my code I've a thread waiting for events on a ZeroMQ endpoint, and its main loop looks similar to this:

```
while (externalCondition) {
  byte[] bytes = subscriber.recv(0);
  // Do things
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to interrupt the call to **`.recv()`** method, if I want to exit the thread (for example because I want to shut down the app).

I tried to interrupt the thread but this seems not to work.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ZeroMQ and distributed system architectures.

### There is no cheap way to interrupt such call <sub>( except a brutal one )</sub>, yet

there is an easy way to re-factor the idea, so as it can work in distributed system realms:

```
/* THIS CODE IS NOT A COPY+PASTE SYNDROME-PROOF, BUT HAS THE DESIGN IDEA CLEAR,
        CODE IS NOT A READY TO RUN, AS THE TARGET LANGUAGE
                AND THE ACTUAL ZeroMQ BINDING / VERSION
                                      WILL DECIDE ON FURTHER DETAILS TO CODE IN
   */
while ( True ) { // -[NEVER-BLOCK]----------- aSoftRealTIME-control-loop-<body>--

   bool ec = externalCondition;
   int  rc = subscriber.poll( someSoftRealTimeDELAY_in_ms );

   if ( ec
      & rc == 0
        ){
        //--------------------------------------------------
       // DO NOTHING, AS THERE IS NOTHING TO WORK ON
      //  or sleep, or
     //   DO ANY SoftRealTime-controlled / yet interruptible
    //           maintenance workpackage(s)
   //-------------------------------------------------------
   }
   if ( !ec ){
        break; // __________________________ J.I.T. / JMP / RET __^
   }
   if (  rc < 0 ){
               // ZeroMQ .poll() Error Analysis & Error Recovery
   }
   if (  rc > 0 ){

               // ZeroMQ has a thing to indeed .recv(), so read it:
         byte[] bytes = subscriber.recv( zmq.DONTWAIT );

         ...   // DO things ... on bytes ...
   }
}  // ---------------[NEVER-BLOCK]----------- aSoftRealTIME-control-loop-<body>--
```

### Nota bene

while this remark might be a fairly well know subject for you, in case you have already got familiar with ZeroMQ internalities and various defaults, yet, let me mention it also here, as not all kind reader may have such deep ZeroMQ practice.

The **`SUB`**-side(s) of the Scalable Formal Communication Pattern used above has a dark-side. Unless one explicitly "subscribed" to some newspapers and/or magazine(s), there will nothing arrive into one's `SUB`-side mailbox, nothing gets delivered at all, as the "delivery service" has not received any subscription from you, telling 'em what you would like to ( receive ) and read

So, always do not forget to submit a call to such a

`subscriber.setsockopt( aSubject_What_To_Subscribe_To_Indeed_Receive_STRING );`

Not having done so, one will never `.recv()` a single byte.

---

> Thanks. **What would be the "brutal" one?** –[Alessandro Polverini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475212/alessandro-polverini) <sub>[23 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350765/how-to-interrupt-a-call-to-read-method-on-a-jeromq-socket#comment85714862_49353159)</sub>

Well, ZeroMQ native API, as of 2018-Q1 permits one, rather brutal way to achieve an enforced interruption of a blocking call to **`.recv()`** method - calling a **`<Context>.term()`** - so, it works more less like a "**Demolition Man**" when asking just for a few pieces of paper ... indeed that way, plus there are further pre-requisities **not to hang** your further code-execution in an uncontrolled zombie-alike state, if not infinitely ( if not having protected all your **`Socket`**-instances generated from native-API with an immediately configured **`.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 1 )`** ( since  native API 2.1+ ~ 4.(?) where a promised change of defaults was published ... respective language binding / wrappers differ in version adoption, so cannot refer in general and best check the [jeromq](/questions/tagged/jeromq) right upon instantiations took place with published **`.getLinger()`**-exposed method to see this reactively per-incident :o) ).

Calling a WMD-alike annihilation, using **`.term()`**-method, will in those cases, where `Socket`-instances were not left waiting ( indeterminatly, if not infinitely ) by **`zmq.LINGER`**-instance attribute, cancel internal-FSA and exit even the still blocked-**`{ .recv() | .send() | poll() }`**-s and return the code-execution control-path to your "**Demolition Man**"-controls :o)

Doable, but a bit harsh, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks. What would be the "brutal" one?

Comment: ... you would not like to use it, believe me. If indeed interested, feel free to accept this Answer, that has addressed the constructive approach to a common-sense working concept and open another one, asking about an ugly practice of going rather in an anti-pattern direction. That's fair, isn't it? :o)

Comment: ZMQ.Socket has no setsockopt() nor poll() methods:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.zeromq/jeromq/0.4.3/org/zeromq/ZMQ.Socket.html

Comment: @AlessandroPolverini ... as has been expressed from the very initial rows in the answer, the ZeroMQ native API does expose both of these very efficient configuration and non-blocking operations tools. Check how the native API was re-wrapped into your target language domain, have met many 3rd Pty API-bindings, that ignored some of the ZeroMQ exposed native-API tools. **In case your current wrapper / language binding does not support the complete native-API, better check for a more complete one, or extend the so far incomplete one, if you prefer to stay with it.** That is fair, isn't it? :o)

Comment: ... a few minutes read yielded a well documented both the subscription setup mechanics and the directly available **`Poller()`**-class, having an exposed class-method **`int .poll( long aTimeOut )`** so keep walking, ... >>> https://static.javadoc.io/org.zeromq/jeromq/0.4.3/org/zeromq/ZMQ.Poller.html